# gfortran openmp segmentation fault occurs on basic do loop

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, gfortran, openmp

I have a program which distributes particles into a cloud-in-cell mesh. Simply loops over the total number of particles (Ntot) and populates a 256^3 mesh (i.e. each particle gets distributed over 8 cells).

```
% gfortran -fopenmp cic.f90 -o ./cic
```

Which compiles fine. But when I run it (./cic) I get a segmentation fault. I my looping is a classic omp do problem. The program works when I don't compile it in openmp.

```
!$omp parallel do
 do i = 1,Ntot
   if (x1(i).gt.0.and.y1(i).gt.0.and.z1(i).gt.0) then
     dense(int(x1(i)),int(y1(i)),int(z1(i))) = dense(int(x1(i)),int(y1(i)),int(z1(i))) &
     + dx1(i) * dy1(i) * dz1(i) * mpart
   end if

   if (x2(i).le.Ng.and.y1(i).gt.0.and.z1(i).gt.0) then
     dense(int(x2(i)),int(y1(i)),int(z1(i))) = dense(int(x2(i)),int(y1(i)),int(z1(i))) &
     + dx2(i) * dy1(i) * dz1(i) * mpart
   end if

   if (x1(i).gt.0.and.y2(i).le.Ng.and.z1(i).gt.0) then
     dense(int(x1(i)),int(y2(i)),int(z1(i))) = dense(int(x1(i)),int(y2(i)),int(z1(i))) &
     + dx1(i) * dy2(i) * dz1(i) * mpart
   end if

   if (x2(i).le.Ng.and.y2(i).le.Ng.and.z1(i).gt.0) then
     dense(int(x2(i)),int(y2(i)),int(z1(i))) = dense(int(x2(i)),int(y2(i)),int(z1(i))) &
     + dx2(i) * dy2(i) * dz1(i) * mpart
   end if

   if (x1(i).gt.0.and.y1(i).gt.0.and.z2(i).le.Ng) then
     dense(int(x1(i)),int(y1(i)),int(z2(i))) = dense(int(x1(i)),int(y1(i)),int(z2(i))) &
     + dx1(i) * dy1(i) * dz2(i) * mpart
   end if

   if (x2(i).le.Ng.and.y1(i).gt.0.and.z2(i).le.Ng) then
     dense(int(x2(i)),int(y1(i)),int(z2(i))) = dense(int(x2(i)),int(y1(i)),int(z2(i))) &
     + dx2(i) * dy1(i) * dz2(i) * mpart
   end if

   if (x1(i).gt.0.and.y2(i).le.Ng.and.z2(i).le.Ng) then
     dense(int(x1(i)),int(y2(i)),int(z2(i))) = dense(int(x1(i)),int(y2(i)),int(z2(i))) &
     + dx1(i) * dy2(i) * dz2(i) * mpart
   end if

   if (x2(i).le.Ng.and.y2(i).le.Ng.and.z2(i).le.Ng) then
     dense(int(x2(i)),int(y2(i)),int(z2(i))) = dense(int(x2(i)),int(y2(i)),int(z2(i))) &
     +  dx2(i) * dy2(i) * dz2(i) * mpart
   end if
  end do
!$omp end parallel do
```

There are no dependencies between iterations. Ideas?

Comment: It seems that you haven't declared any variables to be shared or private, so it's not surprising that you get segfaults.

Comment: Could you be a little more helpful/specific please? "dense" is the only variable each thread will be feeding back into so presumably that is shared. All of the rest are independent. Are there any compiling flags I could use to locate where it is going wrong?

Comment: How is `dense` declared? Is it an automatic array, is it `save`'d or is it `allocatable` and how exactly is it allocated?

Comment: Note beside: I have good experience with the free Solaris Studio's data race analyzer. It can speed up the search for the error location considerably.

Comment: dense is static allocated at the very beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem, as well as the one in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883338/illegal-instruction-4-error-running-simple-gfortran-openmp-on-mac-osx), comes from the fact that automatic heap arrays are disabled when OpenMP is enabled. This means that without `-fopenmp`, big arrays are automatically placed in the static storage (known as the `.bss` segment) while small arrays are allocated on the stack. When you switch OpenMP support on, no automatic static allocation is used and your `dense` arrays gets allocated on the stack of the routine. The default stack limits on OS X are very restrictive, hence the segmentation fault.

You have several options here. The first option is to make `dense` have static allocation by giving it the `SAVE` attribute. The other option is to explicitly allocate it on the heap by making it `ALLOCATABLE` and then using the `ALLOCATE` statement, e.g.:

```
REAL, DIMENSION(:,:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: dense

ALLOCATE(dense(256,256,256))

! Computations, computations, computations

DEALLOCATE(dense)
```

Newer Fortran versions support automatic deallocation of arrays without the `SAVE` attribute when they go out of scope.

Note that your OpenMP directive is just fine and no additional data sharing clauses are necessary. You do not need to declare `i` in a `PRIVATE` clause since loop counters have predetermined private data-sharing class. You do not need to put the other variables in  `SHARED` clause as they are implicitly shared. Yet the operations that you do on `dense` should either be synchronised with `ATOMIC UPDATE` (or simply `ATOMIC` on older OpenMP implementations) or you should use `REDUCTION(+:dense)`. Atomic updates are translated to locked additions and should not incur much of a slowdown, compared to the huge slowdown from having conditionals inside the loop:

```
INTEGER :: xi, yi, zi

!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(xi,yi,zi)
...
if (x1(i).gt.0.and.y1(i).gt.0.and.z1(i).gt.0) then
  xi = int(x1(i))
  yi = int(y1(i))
  zi = int(z1(i))
  !$OMP ATOMIC UPDATE
  dense(xi,yi,zi) = dense(xi,yi,zi) &
                  + dx1(i) * dy1(i) * dz1(i) * mpart
end if
...
```

Replicate the code with the proper changes for the other cases. If your compiler complains about the `UPDATE` clause in the `ATOMIC` construct, simply delete it.

`REDUCTION(+:dense)` would create one copy of `dense` in each thread, which would consume a lot of memory and the reduction applied in the end would grow slower and slower with the size of `dense`. For small arrays it would work better than atomic updates.

Comment: Thanks Hristo - I already had allocated dense exactly how you specified. So I can essentially delete both the shared and private components because it is implicit. Where should I use the ATOMIC UPDATE? Thanks.

Comment: I presume that needs a !$OMP END PARALLEL DO at the end and the PRIVATE statement is just before the inner loop, not on the outside.

Comment: @Griff, yes, the `PARALLEL DO` is there just to show where the `PRIVATE` clause goes - basically this is the `parallel do` from your original code. I've just added the three helper variables that need to be private. In your code there is only one parallel region, whether it encompass the inner loop only or also the outer loop, as I've shown you possible in you other question.

Comment: OK Thanks. It still isn't working. I"m not asking you to go through line by line but if there is anything that stands out here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22892859/cic_openmp_test2.f90 could you let me know. Perhaps a casual check I am doing the things you are saying correctly would help. You've already been very helpful and I don't want to take up too much more of your time. Thanks.

Comment: @Griff, you haven't made allocatable the largest array, `dense`. It occupies 1 GiB and this is way more that the default stack size limit on OS X.

Comment: I thought real(kind=kind(0.0d0)), dimension(int(Ng),int(Ng),int(Ng)) :: dense allocates it as static. How can I increase the stack size? Even when I run it on a cluster at work, I still get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Griff, I think I have written it clearly, that automatic static allocation is disabled when OpenMP is used. To give the array static allocation, add `save` to its attributes: `real(kind=kind(0.0d0)), dimension(...), save :: dense`. The hard stack limit on OS X is 64 MiB, the soft limit is 8 MiB. In order to increase the stack size limit, you have to recompile the OS Darwin kernel :) On Linux it is usually enough to issue `ulimit -s unlimited` if the hard limit is unlimited (and it often is).

Comment: It worked on the cluster. Thank-you very much Hristo and I'm sorry for all of my questions. I think I should delete this thread because it is of little use to anyone. Thank-you very much again.

Answer (score -1):

See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#Clauses for a description of how to make variables shared and private.

It looks like all your variables should be shared, except the loop variable `i` which must be private.  This would suggest using the following line:

```
!$omp parallel do default(shared) private(i)
```

This should fix your segmentation fault (assuming I got all the variables correct

However, there is the risk that different threads will attempt to overwrite the same parts of `dense` simultaneously, resulting in incorrect totals. To protect against this case, you will need to wrap each assignment to `dense` within something like an `!$omp atomic`  or `!$omp critical` section.

However, you may find that such critical sections will cause threads to spend most of their time waiting, so you may not see any improvement over purely serial code.

In principal you could solve this problem by declaring `dense` with the `reduction` keyword, but unfortunately it cannot be used for arrays.

Comment: Neither `default(shared)` nor `private(i)` would change anything in this case as in Fortran OpenMP variables are implicitly `shared` by default unless declared `threadprivate` and the loop counter has a predetermined `private` data-sharing attribute.

Comment: The `reduction` clause does not accept arrays in C/C++ only. In Fortran arrays are perfectly acceptable for reduction, even allocatable ones.

Comment: This loop above is within another loop which doesn't need to be in parallel - it only loops 4 times. Do I need to specify what to do with this outer loop? The only thing I want parallel is the loop above.