# Illegal instruction error when running openMP in gfortran mac

Tags: macos, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I am new to openMP so bear with me. I use a macbook pro with OX Mavericks and installed a version of gfortran compatible with my OS.

I implemented a very simple dynamic programming problem to solve something that economist call the Neoclassical Growth Model.

I find no problem when I run it without openMP, however when trying to compile the program with -fopenmp option I get either

Illegal Instruction: 4 or
Segmentation Fault: 11

... probably I am doing something very wrong.

I attach the main program, subroutines, modules and .sh compilation file

```
PROGRAM prg_dp1

    ! PRG_DP1 SOLVES THE GROWTH MODEL BY VALUE FUNCTION ITERATION OVER A DISCRETE GRID
    ! WITHOUT INTERPOLATION. EVALUATION IS DONE OVER NEXT PERIOD CAPITAL

    ! PROBLEM: PROGRAMMED AS MATRICES IT LIMITS THE SIZE OF THE PROGRAM BEFORE !SEGMENTATION FAULTS OCCUR

    USE modvar

    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(nk) :: v,v0,kp,c
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(nk,nk) :: cm,um,vm
    REAL(DP) :: kstar,tbegin,tend
    INTEGER :: it,ik1,ik2,ind(nk)

    ! INVOCATION OF THE OUTPUT FILES WHERE THE INFORMATION IS GOING TO BE WRITTEN
    CALL CPU_TIME(tbegin)


    ! DEFINITION OF THE PARAMETERS OF THE MODEL

    p(1)=1.0001     ! Intertemporal elasticity of substitution (SIGMA)
    p(2)=0.96       ! Intertemporal discount factor (BETA)
    p(3)=0.06       ! Depreciation rate (DELTA)
    p(4)=0.36       ! Share of capital in production (ALPHA)
    p(5)=0.00       ! (Parameter not needed)

    ! COMPUTATION OF THE STEADY STATE CAPITAL STOCK

    kstar=((1.0/p(2)-(1.0-p(3)))/p(4))**(1.0/(p(4)-1.0))

    ! FIRST I ALLOCATE AND CONSTRUCT THE GRID

    slope=1.0
    gkmin=0.0001
    gkmax=5.0*kstar
  !  ALLOCATE(gk(nk),ones(nk,nk))

    ALLOCATE(gk(nk))
!   ones=1.0
    CALL sub_grid_generation(gk,nk,slope,gkmin,gkmax)

    ! DEFINITION OF THE MATRICES OF CONSUMPTION AND UTILITY

    !$OMP PARALLEL  DEFAULT(SHARED) PRIVATE(ik1,ik2)
    !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC)
    DO ik1=1,nk
        DO ik2=1,nk
            cm(ik1,ik2)=gk(ik1)**p(4)+(1.0-p(3))*gk(ik1)-gk(ik2)
        END DO
    END DO
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL

   ! cm = gk**p(4)+(1.0-p(3))*gk-gk*ones


    WHERE (cm .le. 0.0)
        um=-1.0e+6
    ELSEWHERE
        um=(cm**(1.0-p(1))-1.0)/(1.0-p(1))
    END WHERE

    ! DINAMIC PROGRAMMING STEP

    ! I first initialize the value function to zeros

    v0=0.0

    ! Main do has to be done by master-thread ... can I parallelize more?

    DO
        !$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(ik2)
        DO ik2=1,nk
            vm(:,ik2)=um(:,ik2)+p(2)*v0(ik2)
        END DO
        !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
        v=MAXVAL(vm,DIM=2)
        print *, MAXVAL(ABS(v-v0))
        IF (MAXVAL(ABS(v-v0)) .le. dp_tol) THEN
            EXIT
        ELSE
            v0=v
        END IF
    END DO

    ind=MAXLOC(v,DIM=1)

    kp=gk(ind)
    c=gk**p(4)+(1.0-p(3))*gk-kp
    open(unit=1,file='output.txt')
    DO ik1=1,nk
        write(1,'(4F10.5)') gk(ik1),v(ik1),kp(ik1),c(ik1)
    END DO
    close(1)
    DEALLOCATE(gk)

    CALL CPU_TIME(tend)

    PRINT *, tend-tbegin

END PROGRAM prg_dp1

SUBROUTINE sub_grid_generation(grid,gsize,slope,gridmin,gridmax)
    USE nrtype
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: gsize
    REAL(DP), INTENT(IN) :: slope,gridmin,gridmax
REAL(DP), INTENT(OUT) :: grid(gsize)
    INTEGER :: ig   
grid(1)=gridmin
    DO ig=2,gsize
    grid(ig)=gridmin+((gridmax-gridmin)/dfloat(gsize)**slope)*dfloat(ig)**slope
    END DO
```

END SUBROUTINE sub_grid_generation

```
MODULE nrtype
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I4B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I2B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(4)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: I1B = SELECTED_INT_KIND(2)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SP = KIND(1.0)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = KIND(1.0D0)
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SPC = KIND((1.0,1.0))
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DPC = KIND((1.0D0,1.0D0))
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: LGT = KIND(.true.)
    REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: PI=3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_sp
    REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: PIO2=1.57079632679489661923132169163975144209858_sp
    REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: TWOPI=6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394_sp
    REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: SQRT2=1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967_sp
    REAL(SP), PARAMETER :: EULER=0.5772156649015328606065120900824024310422_sp
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: PI_D=3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197_dp
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: PIO2_D=1.57079632679489661923132169163975144209858_dp
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: TWOPI_D=6.283185307179586476925286766559005768394_dp
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: gr=(5.0**0.5-1.0)/2.0
    TYPE sprs2_sp
        INTEGER(I4B) :: n,len
        REAL(SP), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: val
        INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: irow
        INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: jcol
    END TYPE sprs2_sp
    TYPE sprs2_dp
        INTEGER(I4B) :: n,len
        REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: val
        INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: irow
        INTEGER(I4B), DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: jcol
    END TYPE sprs2_dp
END MODULE nrtype

MODULE modvar
    USE nrtype
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: r_tol=1e-8
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: p_tol=1e-6

    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: dp_tol=1e-6
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: c_tol=0.001
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: adj=0.5

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: r_m=10000

    ! PARAMETER THAT DEFINE THE DIMENSION OF THE PROBLEM

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nk=5000
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nz=21
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: np=20000
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nt=5000

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: maxit=10000

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dist_maxit=5000

    ! POLICY PARAMETER, COMMON ENDOGENOUS VARIABLES AND OTHER ALLOCATABLE ARRAYS

    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: nw=0.0
    REAL(DP), PARAMETER :: ft=0.33
    REAL(DP) :: p(5),gkmin,gkmax,slope
    REAL(DP), ALLOCATABLE :: gk(:),gz(:),m(:,:),mss(:),ones(:,:)
END MODULE modvar
```

and the .sh file I use to compile

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
gfortran -O2 -fopenmp -c nrtype.f90 modvar.f90 sub_grid_generation.f90 prg_dp1.f90

gfortran -O2 -fopenmp -fcheck=bounds -o myprog nrtype.o modvar.o sub_grid_generation.o prg_dp1.o
```

---

I know this is tedious but I would appreciate some help

Thank you

Comment: You might want to take a look at [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870564/gfortran-openmp-segmentation-fault-occurs-on-basic-do-loop) that your is practically a duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other options is to make the global arrays `cm,um,vm`, and possibly also the smaller other ones, allocatable. This will become handy when you change the problem size, read it from somewhere and maintain the executable.

```
REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:,:),allocatable :: cm,um,vm

allocate(cm(nk,nk),um(nk,nk),vm(nk,nk))
```

Comment: I didn't think of that, that's probably a better solution than mine.

Comment: It worked pretty well... I guess that I yet not fully understand why

Comment: Because the allocatable arrays are placed in a different part of memory called heap, which can be as large as your machine's memory. The stack where they were placed by tho compiler before is much smaller.

Answer (score 2):

It is a stack space issue. I tried running it with ifort and even without openmp I get illegal instruction and I had to specify -heap-arrays in order to get it to run properly. Once I added openmp the illegal instruction error came back. The `WHERE` statement seems to be the problem code. In both the openmp and non-openmp runs that is the part that causes it to fail

OS X stack space is rather limited and you are creating large arrays. Using -heap-arrays helps, but once you use openmp that is no longer a possibility and ulimit is maxed out as ~64 MB.

I found adding this to your compilation works:

```
-Wl,-stack_size,0x40000000,-stack_addr,0xf0000000
```

Which increases the stack size to 1GB. This could probably be fine tuned, but I tried using 256 MB and it was still not enough.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful... However I wonder why it did not work in an amazon linux ec2 instance where I set the stack size to be unlimited