# problem with !$OMP PARALLEL in fortran & segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp, gfortran, reduction

I'm fairly new to fortran and very new to openmp. I have inherited a fortran code from a colleague, and I'm requested to parallelize it using openmp. The code was originally translated from matlab, and runs fine without openmp. But when I try to parallelize it, I'm having different issues.

I have a just one do loop that inside contains several calculations, such as: maxval, reshape, sum, product and a couple of where statements (I'm copying some of the code below). I was reading tutorials and some recommended using a critical section, others reduction and others workshare. The code right now is as follows, I'm not showing all the variables because it will be much longer:

```
subroutine COMPUTE_RIM(variables)
    use hdf5   
    use omp_lib
    use precision, only: pr => sp !it's a module to define number precision, I'm using single prec.
    implicit none
    
    !variable declaration. I'm showing some as an example
    integer                                    :: NAN = -9999
    integer(hsize_t),dimension(1:2)            :: lat_dims
    real(pr),dimension(480,1440,96)            :: precipitation_new
    real(pr)                                   :: dilf,rim,hyc,pick
    real(pr),allocatable,dimension(:)          :: dilIns,dil,wVec
    real(pr),allocatable,dimension(:,:)        :: t_rain,dil_Hyst,dilM,cc,time
    integer                                    :: a,b,aa,bb,id1,kz1,cc2,timeIns
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)           :: lat_indF,long_indF,ind_rowF,ind_colF,indNan2
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:,:)         :: indNan1
    real(pr),dimension(1,lat_dims(2))          :: sec
    real(pr),dimension(lat_dims(1),lat_dims(2)):: anc_sss
    
    !arrays allocation, I'm showing some
    allocate(sample_time(1,48),t_dif(1,48),t_rain(13,49),t_rain(13,49),indNan1(13,49),indNan2(13))
    allocate(dilM(13,48),time(13,48),cc(13,48),dilIns(13),dil_Hyst(13,49),dil(13))
    allocate(wVec(13),RIM_SSS(lat_dims(1),lat_dims(2)))
    
    !arrays initialization, showing some
    t_rain(:,:) = NAN
    RIM_SSS(:,:) = NAN
    
    !defining parameters
    z = 0.005_pr !just one example, there are more param. that are used in the loop
    
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(b,a,aa,bb,hyc,pick,id1)    
    !$OMP DO  
    do itemp = 1,size(lat_indF)     
       a = ind_rowF(itemp)        
       b = ind_colF(itemp)          
       aa = lat_indF(itemp) - 120     
       bb = long_indF(itemp)         
    
       t_dif = (sample_time - (sec(1,b)/3600._pr))    
       hyc = anc_sss(a,b)     
    
       !$OMP CRITICAL    
            pick = maxval(pack(t_dif,t_dif .lt. 0))
            id1 = maxloc((pack(t_dif,t_dif .lt. 0)),dim=1)    
       !$OMP END CRITICAL
    
       timeIns = -pick*3600._pr;
    
       !$OMP CRITICAL
            t_rain(1,:) = reshape(precipitation_new(aa - 2,bb,id1:id1 + 48),shape(t_rain(1,:)))
       .
       .
       .
       !$OMP END CRITICAL
    
       where (t_rain .ge. 0)
            indNan1 = 1
       elsewhere
            indNan1 = 0
       endwhere
    
       dilM = (1._pr + (((t_rain(:,1:48)*real(indNan1(:,1:48),pr)*(cc/1000._pr))/&
       (sqrt(time*kz1)))*exp((-z**2._pr)/(4._pr*kz1*time))))
       dilIns = (1._pr + (((t_rain(:,49)*real(indNan1(:,49),pr)*((1800._pr*cc2)/&
       3600._pr)/(1000._pr))/(sqrt(timeIns*kz1)))*exp((-z**2._pr)/(4._pr*kz1*timeIns))))
       dil_Hyst(1:13,1:48) = dilM
       dil_Hyst(1:13,49) = dilIns
    
       dil = (product(dil_Hyst,2))**(-1._pr)
       dilf = (sum((dil*wVec*real(indNan2,pr)),1))/(sum(wVec*real(indNan2,pr),1)) 
       rim = hyc*dilf;

       RIM_SSS(a,b) = rim
    enddo
    !$OMP END DO
    !$OMP END PARALLEL\
 !deallocate variables
```

I'm compiling the code as: gfortran -fopenmp -g -fcheck=all main main.f90 (and hdf5 modules)

So far I have tried:

1. The code as is, compiles and runs (given that I do ulimit -s unlimited), but yields the wrong result. It's similar to what should be, but has a lot of noise (contamination, values either huge or super small. The variable rim should not be bigger than 50 or smaller than 0, except closer to the borders where undefinded and should be -9999 or NaN).
2. Even when the code is running as is, doing perf stat ./main gives a segmentation fault.
3. If I don't do ulimit -s unlimited I get segmentation fault.
4. If I add a WORKSHARE to the !$OMP PARALLEL it does not recognize the !$OMP DO. It says: Unexpected !$OMP DO statement at (1).

I read on another post that I could do vagrind ./main, and I get:

```
==6309== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x1ffefffd28 --> 0x1fdf5bf7d0
==6309==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=530842968 or greater
==6309== Invalid write of size 8
==6309==    at 0x115974: MAIN__ (main_omp.f90:6)
==6309==  Address 0x1fdf5bf9f8 is on thread 1's stack
==6309== 
==6309== Can't extend stack to 0x1fdf5be888 during signal delivery for thread 1:
==6309==   no stack segment
```

Because of my inexperience I'm unable to understand if I have a fundamental error or a basic mistake. Am I using the openmp directives in a wrong way, or I'm missing some?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The very first thing that I see here is that you are misusing the `reduction` clause. `reduction(+:)` is for variables where you accumulate a result (typically doing something like `a = a + 1`). But since you're not in that case, the variables you declared `reduction` should rather be declared `private`. That is just for a starter.

Comment: Or not... Actually, rereading the code, it might be that you'd need declaring some `reduction(max:)` rather than `reduction(+:)`. But even if that might work for `pick` (supposing I understand what the code is doing), it likely won't work for `id1`. There, you'll have to manage it by hand with an `if` statement into some `critical` section.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean about reduction, I completely misunderstood how to use it, thanks for the comments. However, shouldn't I use reduction for dil and dilf, since I'm multiplying and adding the elements of a vector?

Comment: For what I can see, neither of the two is used for accumulating (no use like `dil=dil*something`) so they shouldn't be declared `reduction(*:)`.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortan questions? BTW, why do you `use omp_lib`? Some people belive it is always necessary but it is only necessary for the explicit interface to certain OpenMP procedures.

Comment: Thanks for tag. As I said, I'm new to openmp, all the tutorials I've seen start with saying I needed to add omp_lib...

Comment: The OpenMP `workshare` construct is meant to be used with Fortran constructs and intrinsics that have hidden loops, e.g., array assingment `A(:) = B(:) + C(:)`, `WHERE`, `FORALL`, `MATMUL`, etc. You cannot nest a `do` construct inside, but you can nest a `parallel` region.

Comment: For the reason your code doesn't run without `ulimit -s unlimited`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13884056/1374437).

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev. I do have where, prod and sum in my code, that's why I was trying to use workshare. I'll try nesting a parallel region.
And yes, it does not run without making the stack mem unlimited, which I don't think it should be. However, even when it runs it does not get the correct result, as I start adding threads I see the results become more and more noisy, and the values just go crazy. Typically, rim should give 0:45 (except when there are no values that is -9999), and I get -10^5:10^5

Comment: Your code shouldn't run without modification to the stack size even without OpenMP. It runs because GNU Fortran has automatic heap arrays and it allocates non-ALLOCATABLE arrays over a given size on the heap and not on the stack. OpenMP disables this feature for a variety of reasons and big arrays such as `precipitation_new` overflow the stack. As to the wrong results, those are likely due to data races.

Comment: I see, I didn't know the details about how fortran was allocating the arrays. Thank you @HristoIliev.
Although I don't know much, I suspected since the beginning that the problem was some issue with threads accessing the same

Comment: ...variable at the same time. However, I don't know how to fix it. I did try putting every variable that is created inside the loop as private, but I still get the wrong result.Any suggestions? 
I'm going to double check that I have not missed one or some in the declaration.
Sorry, my 1 year old press the enter key!